# create a form in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to create a form like this in Zend Framework :

```
<form action="some action" method="post">
    <div class="login_form">
        <h3>Admin Login</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="login_user">
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
            </li>
            <li class="login_pass">
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="login_btn blue_lgel" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

How can i make it possible using zend_form class??
I am just new to the zend framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, have a look at the documentation:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html

That's what it's for: it's written to answer questions like yours.

Your code will look something like:

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAction('/myUrl')
             ->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement('text', 'username', array('required' => true));
        $this->addElement('password', 'passw', array('required' => true));
    }
}
```

Then in your controller's action:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $this->view->myForm = new MyForm();
}
```

And in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->myForm; ?>
```

Comment: thanks brother for your response. It just created the form and worked properly, but the form is generated in the DtDd wrapper in viewed source but i want the form exact looking like as my html code.
how can i make it possible as fast as i can??

Comment: @KeyurPanchal use the viewScript Decorator. It's in the manual.